# Use Landsat imagery to create NAIP equivalent

Tags: landsat, naip

I was wondering if anyone knows if I may be able to create a NAIP equivalent using Landsat imagery. If so, how?

Comment: There is nothing like enough resolution in Landsat to get equivalent resolution. Perhaps you can provide some more details on what you're really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @BradHards.  It depends on what specifications you want/need and applications for use.  NAIP is flown for agricultural purposes.  As such the time collected is usually at peak ground cover.  If your intended use involves applications relating to ground cover, ecology studies, etc. then Landsat may serve your purpose.  I think your question needs to be revised to include what applications you're looking to use it for, resolution needs, frequency of updates, and so forth.